# Dfango function view VS class RedirectView. How to make class view accept arguments

Tags: python, django, generics, view

Function as a view knows question, but class does not (args,kwargs are from url, empty, post method has only choice , but not question).
Both work, but for adding checks I would like to know how to get question in class. Its init or get_redirect_url or request have nothing inside like question_id

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'polls'
ulrpatterns=[
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('<int:pk>/vote0/', views.vote0.as_view(), name='vote0'),
]
```

views.py

```
class vote0(generic.base.RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'polls:results'
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, pk(self.request.POST['choice']))
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: The named ones are in the `**kwargs`, or you can use `self.kwargs`, and/or `self.args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_redirect_url` is provided with the *named* URL parameters (the `**kwargs`), so you can rewrite the signature to catch these. For example:

```
class vote0(generic.base.RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'polls:results'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, question_id=None, **kwargs):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can access *positional* URL parameters in `self.args`, and *named* URL parameters in `self.kwargs` as well.

## Background

If we look at the ["derived"](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.base/RedirectView/#post) implementation, we see that if we would have constructed a `RedirectView` just as a plain view, it would look like:

```
class RedirectView(View):

    # ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = self.get_redirect_url(**kwargs)
        if url:
            if self.permanent:
                return http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
            else:
                return http.HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            logger.warning('Gone: %s', self.request.path,
                        extra={
                            'status_code': 410,
                            'request': self.request
                        })
            return http.HttpResponseGone()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The dispatcher thus will call `post` (which simply wraps `get`), or `get` directly. The `get(..)` function will make a call and pass the `**kwargs` parameters.

Comment: THank you for answer and highlight.
WHen I gave it a try to print args,kwargs,self.request["POST"], it showed that 'pk' item of kwargs has what I needed!
(for some reason kwargs were always empty yesterday)